# Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator

Tags: sql, view, operator-keyword

I have this SQL view query.

```
SUM('ValueFC') AS VALUEFC_0 .....

........
 SUM(g.AMTCUR_0 * g.SNS_0 * - 1) AS 'ValueFC',
```

Whenever I run it it says " Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator"

Answer (score 1):

In `SUM('ValueFC')` aggregate the `'ValueFC'` will be considered as string since it enclosed with *single quotes* so the error.

Since it as *alias* name in `sub-select` or `derived query` you can use the name directly in sum aggregate to pull the values like

```
SUM(ValueFC) AS VALUEFC_0 .....

    ........
 SUM(g.AMTCUR_0 * g.SNS_0 * - 1) AS 'ValueFC',
```

Comment: Error still the same.

Comment: SELECT ......., SUM(ValueFC) AS VALUEFC_0, 
              ............
FROM  (SELECT , SUM(g.AMTCUR_0 * g.SNS_0 * - 1) AS 'ValueFC',..........

Answer (score 0):

After changind it like this

SUM(CAST('ValueFC' AS INT)) AS VALUEFC_0,

The error now says 
"Conversion failed when converting varchar value 'VALUEFC' to data int